# in magento, how to clear user account dashboard?

Tags: magento-1.9, dashboard

It is required to totally clear the account dashboard page, to display custom layout which varies according to logged in customer's user group.
I did the following:

```
<customer_account_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="MyModule/Dashboard" name="block_Dashboard" template="customer/Dashboard.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

I can see the output of 'customer/Dashboard.phtml', but how to remove all of these widgets?

```
Account Information
Contact Information
...
```

Can't find any layout handlers, nor the template reference for them in app/core/Mage/Customer/*

Where to dig ? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was inside the app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml under the customer_account_index node.